# DNS Active Directory Zone Replication Scope (Forest vs Domain)

Tags: domain-controller, replication, reverse-dns

When I create a new Domain Controller with dcpromo then the wizard will also add a DNS Role to the server because the first domain controller must be the global catalog server for the forest.

After the install when I look at the DNS then I see the forward lookup zone for the newly created domain.

However no zone is created for the Reverse lookup zone.

When configuring the new rDNS zone I am asked about the replication scope.

I am going to have 3 trees in my forest (business1.com - business2.com - business3.com)

Should I choose Forest rDNS replication Zone in my very first Domain Controller?

**I don't understand what would be the difference on just choosing Domain replication scope.**

Thanks in advance for the info and your time.

Answer (score 0):

1. A reverse lookup zone isn't created automatically because it's not a component of Active Directory. AD doesn't require a reverse lookup zone and doesn't use a reverse lookup zone. Creating a reverse lookup zone is completely up to you.
2. A reverse lookup zone doesn't have any relation to how many domains exist in your Forest.
3. How many reverse lookup zones are there? Is each Domain using a different Layer 3 ip addressing scheme? Where do you want the reverse lookup zones to be available? Do you want them to be available to all domain members in the entire Forest? If so, then set the replication scope to Forest wide. Do you want the reverse lookup zones to be available only to the applicable domain members in each Domain? If so, then set the replication scope to Domain.